# Yahoo Currency Converter API

Tags: java, yql

I've been using the Yahoo Currency Converter all along without issues.

Here is the function code in Java:

```
 public static Float convert(String currencyFrom, String currencyTo) throws IOException {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + currencyFrom + currencyTo + "=X&f=l1&e=.csv");
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    return Float.parseFloat(responseBody);

 }
```

However, just yesterday I realised it was throwing the following error:

> It has come to our attention that this service is being used in
>   violation of the Yahoo Terms of Service. As such, the service is being
>   discontinued. For all future markets and equities data research,
>   please refer to finance.yahoo.com.

Is there some problems with the code I'm using? Or has the service been discontinued permanently. Any alternative suggestion for real time currency conversion?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. It seems that yahoo has shut down the service.

Comment: Fixer.io and Openexchangerates.org seem to be the best alternatives as of today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that the service has been discontinued overnight.

https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/http-download-finance-yahoo-com-d-quotes-csv-s-GOOG-amp-f/m-p/387662/highlight/true#M6207

This is the answer from the admin of the community site.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Although discontinued, you could look at an alternative such as http://fixer.io, which would allow you to do something similar via JSON

https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=currencyFrom&symbols=currencyTo

Comment: unfortunately fixer.io covers only 30 currencies, yahoo had 160 currencies.

Comment: Ahhh, good to know.

Comment: They offer 170 currencies now, and it was very quick to setup. I would recommend them.

Comment: fixer does not respond, gets timedout

Comment: Fixer updated their API

https://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=API_KEY&base=USD&symbols=GBP,JPY,EUR